# SOLR query length issue

Tags: post, curl, solr

I have to run a long solr query. But when I try it will not provide no output, only blank page. Is their any query length limit / config in solr. I am using apache server, there is no limit configured.

If i reduce the query length It will work.

Also I am using Curl for connection. Please help me to solve the issue.

Curl I am using

```
public static function getDataThroughCurl($url,$ch)
{ 
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        throw new CHttpException(404,'Sorry cURL is not installed'); 
    } 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'f48be786f212f1e35dd965b4675358123d838e53:X');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    echo curl_error($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Check whether this addresses your query   http://serverfault.com/questions/136249/how-do-we-increase-the-maximum-allowed-http-get-query-length-in-jetty

Comment: NO , I am using apache server. Any idea ?

Comment: When you say "Apache server", do you mean Tomcat? In that case the preset maximum length of a URL is 8k... PS Your query is wildly offensive. Flagged it...

Comment: In future, please keep your b*tcht*ts queries to yourself.

Comment: Here is the relevant link for Tomcat: http://serverfault.com/questions/56691/whats-the-maximum-url-length-in-tomcat . In future, fetch the body of the response and examine the errors. An excessively long query also has an error code.

Comment: I am not using Tomcat. ALso do I need any solr memory adjustment ?

Comment: I am using a very long query.  Then only issue occurred, otherwise I have no problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using GET? POST is the wrong semantics for a search query. I'm not sure if Solr is usually configured to answer a POST.

Also, what error code is returned by cURL?

I'm also a little confused about why you are sending user and password. I've never seen Solr configured to require login.

The best way to debug this sort of thing is to compose the query URL, then access Solr from a browser. It is an HTTP server after all. That makes it easier to see what happens.